# Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation from model call by not view in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model, Ability, which  belongs to another model AbilityType.

```
    <?php
class Ability extends Eloquent {

    public function abilityType() {
        return $this->belongsTo('AbilityType');
    }

    public function name() {
        return $this->abilityType->name;
    }
}
```

I can make this call in my blade template successfully:

```
$ability->abilityType->name
```

But when I make that same call in my Ability model, it throws an exception:

```
ErrorException Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

Do the dynamic properties differ in behavior between view and model layer?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code how you call the `abilityType` from within/on your model? Should just be: `$this->abilityType->name` or i.e. in an controller `Ability::find(1)->abilityType->name`.

Answer (score 7):

Laravel uses a special `getFooAttribute` syntax to load dynamic properties:

```
class Ability extends Eloquent {

    public function abilityType ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('AbilityType');
    }

    public function getNameAttribute ()
    {
        return $this->abilityType->name;
    }

}
```